# Suitable architecture for storing "Seen" messages

Tags: php

I'm sure all of you have seen at some point at some website some message - i.e. you logged in and it stated something like "There will be a planned maintenance downtime at Tuesday 5PM PST". And then you have the tick mark for the message. When you click on it, you don't get the message shown any more.

Now, my question is how to handle this in the database. I.e. if you have 1M registered users and you decide to store this "seen" record for every user you'll end up with a 1M table which has to be read from every time someone logs in. On the other hand, if you have 10 messages like that - of course your table grows much faster. And finally, there could be messages like "Johnny,Harry,Diane and 5 of your other friends have updated their profile."

You could have like 10-50 messages like that daily. What I'm trying to think of is the best approach to this. I've implemented a lot of solutions in the past but I'm rethinking and am wondering of how others in the community are handling problems like that!

Edit:
@hakre
Thank you for your comment. Actually, I did describe one way I handled it in the question itself. Don't get me wrong but if I propose solutions, answers tend to discuss those proposed solutions which isn't something I'd like.

Comment: You don't have to read the whole table. That's what indexes are for.

Comment: Think from a technical point of view: if you want to know for each message and each user who checked what message there _cannot_ be an alternative to store each check as a single entry. The only question is if you have to store each check tick in a single row. You can use bitfields for this, this is perfect when looking at space usage, but you will have to try how such bit bitfields /thousands of bits) actually behave. Never tried that.

Comment: So you have done this in the past and you don't want to share what you've done but you ask others to share? Well, I'd say, these things work best if you step out first. Also in it's current form this is pretty broad, I could write you a book about that.

Comment: Surely a cookie would suffice? You do not need a database structure for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any NoSQL at hands?

I use redis, and I would create an set with all the users ids as members of the set (add the ids if the user should be marked as seen)... To check if the user has seen the message a simple `SISMEMBER` will suffice and it's O(1)...

Plus, you won't need any db query or alter table for the `seen` field.

http://redis.io/commands/sismember

Comment: Are you saying you would create a new set for every message?

Comment: No. A single set that stores all the user ids of the people that have seen the message.